# Show button when dataTable rows reduce to one on searching the dataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable, show-hide

I'm using a jQuery dataTable to list a group of members. When the table is searched for a member, and when the dataTable rows reduce to only that member, I want a button to appear, else the button should remain hidden.

I can't find a way to link an even handler to this. Please help me with a solution.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#addButton').hide();
    });
</script>

<script>
    $('#example4_filter input').keydown(function() {
        if ($('#example4 > tr').length == 1) {
            $('#addButton').show();
        } else {
            $('#addButton').hide();
        }
    });
</script>

<table id="example4" class="display table table-bordered table-striped" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
            <col width='110'>
            <col width='auto'>
            <col width='120'>
            <thead height='35'>
                <tr>
                    <th>Code</th>
                    <th>Member Name</th>
                    <th>NIC</th>
                    <th> <p id='addButton'> <a href="{{ url('') }}" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> <strong> &nbsp Select </strong> </a> </p> </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                @foreach ($memberDetails as $memberDetail)
                <tr>
                    <td data-search="Tiger Nixon"> {!! $memberDetail->id !!} </td>
                    <td> {!! $memberDetail->firstName.' '.$memberDetail->lastName !!} </td>
                    <td> {!! $memberDetail->nic !!} </td>
                    <td> </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

this is the inspect element code for the search of dataTable...

```
<div id="example4_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper form-inline dt-bootstrap no-footer">

    <div class="row">
        ::before
        <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div id="example4_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
                <label>

                    Search:

                    <input class="form-control input-sm" type="search" placeholder="" aria-controls="example4"></input>

                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        ::after

    </div>

$('#example4').DataTable({
                "paging": true,
                "lengthChange": false,
                "searching": true,
                "ordering": false,
                "info": false,
                "autoWidth": false,
                "lengthMenu": [[5], [5]]
            });
```

Comment: count the row if length is 1 show button

Comment: ya, but how to do that? I tried but couldn't... this is my code

<script>
            $(function() {
                $('#addButton').hide();
            });
        </script>

        <script>
            $('#example4_filter input').keydown(function() {
                if ($('#example4 > tr').length == 1) {
                    $('#addButton').show();
                } else {
                    $('#addButton').hide();
                }
            });
        </script>

Comment: <script>
            $(function() {
                $('#addButton').hide();
            });
        </script>

        <script>
            $('#example4_filter input').keydown(function() {
                if ($('#example4 > tr').length == 1) {
                    $('#addButton').show();
                } else {
                    $('#addButton').hide();
                }
            });
        </script>

Comment: edit your answer show html and js

Comment: addButton is the <p> elements id that holds the button
example4 is my table id

Comment: did you try it already?

Comment: that is why i said include the html as well

Comment: ok, I added the html too :)

Comment: i dnt see any input box or button

Comment: it comes along with the dataTable plugin

https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/dom.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using dataTables 1.10.x. You can take advantage of the  `search.dt` event. If you have a `table` initialised like this :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({ 
    //options
})
```

use the `search.dt` event to show the button if and only if one record is visible in the dataTable :

```
$('#example').on('search.dt', function() {
   if (table.rows( {filter:'applied'} ).data().length == 1) {
      $('#addButton').show();
   } else {
      $('#addButton').hide();       
   }     
})
```

Comment: is there a way I can add my own columns to the datatable if I use this initializing method you're saying about?

I mean, say I want three columns id, name, age

how to initialize them in this method?

Comment: the thing is, I'm filling the datatable with data from a database, using php, so is it possible to initialize the datatable with those data?

Comment: you said to initialize the datatable with, var table = $('#example').DataTable({ 
    //options
})
but this method cannot be done in my case coz I'm getting data using php from the database, so your method is not practical in here

Comment: @RIzanZaky, I assume you are just doing as you are doing already, you **are** initializing a dataTable, are you not? This is the whole premise for the question. You have a `DataTable()` somewhere, the only reason for me to show `table = $('#example').DataTable({ //options })`  is to explain that you need the `table` variable returned by `DataTable()`.  I did that because you did not include your script in the question.

Comment: oh sorry, it works... I just added var table to the script and used it... thanks a lot

Comment: @RIzanZaky, OK - I must admit I was really confused! The way you described it and the script you have added is totally normal usage.  There should not be anything wrong. Thank you for accepting the answer!